# Create folder in outlook | .Net

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am creating folder in microsoft outlook through .net application BUT it is getting displayed ONLY when I Restart outlook. New folder should be displayed without restarting outlook.
I am using below code:

```
       Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folderInbox = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder               
       (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Outlook.Folders inboxFolders = folderInbox.Folders;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder subfolderInbox = null;

        Outlook.Application oApp;
        oApp = nameSpace.Application;
        Outlook.Explorer exp = oApp.ActiveExplorer();

         subfolderInbox = inboxFolders.Add("InboxSubfolder",  
         Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
         exp.CurrentFolder = subfolderInbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using [Add-in Express](http://www.add-in-express.com).

I attached your code to an adxRibbonButton control and it worked for me.
How are you calling this code? 

I see some unnecessary object creation and removed them in my edited version below.

Also - [you want to make sure to release the Office objects you create](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/).

I recommend updating the code as follows:

```
private void adxRibbonButton1_OnClick(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
    {
        Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = OutlookApp.Session; //OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        Outlook.MAPIFolder folderInbox = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder
       (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Outlook.Folders inboxFolders = folderInbox.Folders;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder subfolderInbox = null;

        //Outlook.Application oApp;
        //oApp = nameSpace.Application;
        Outlook.Explorer exp = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer(); //oApp.ActiveExplorer();

        subfolderInbox = inboxFolders.Add("InboxSubfolder",
            Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            exp.CurrentFolder = subfolderInbox;

        //Release COM Objects
        if (exp != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exp);
        if (subfolderInbox != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(subfolderInbox);
        if (inboxFolders != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inboxFolders);
        if (folderInbox != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderInbox);
        if (nameSpace != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nameSpace);
    }
```

Comment: thx for edited version. I will try and let you know in case of any issue..

I was running this code from static main method in console application .

Just need to check with you that I have set up password to open outlook. Could this be the 
reason that new folder is getting displayed only when i restart outlook?